# How is this formula written in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, formula

Equation:

[image]

```
import numpy as np

# 'RT' is given or calculated
rcaps = int(input('please enter the number of R:'))

# a list of the 'N' values, I think this is given,
# or calculated from another formula
ncaps=[12,21,35]

# 'T' is the length of ncaps
tcaps = len(ncaps)

# Delta is given or calculated
delta = int(input('please enter the number of Delta:'))

def equation(rcaps, delta):
    # get the value of 'Nt'
    i = 0
    while i < tcaps:
        ncapst = ncaps[i]
        # x = the sum of 1-delta to the power of t-1 from t= 1 to T multiplied by 3 
        x = 0
        for t in range(1, tcaps+1):
            x += (1-delta)**(t-1)
            t += 1
        x * 3
        # y = the sum of 1- delta to the power ot t from t= 1 to T-1 multiplied by 2 
        y = 0
        for f in range(1, tcaps):
            y += (1-delta)**f
            f += 1
        y * 2

        print(np.dot(rcaps/(x-y), 1/ncapst)) 

        i += 1
```

I tried to write the equation above in python.
I still don't have the Rt and Delta values, so I assumed that they are given by the user from another calculations.
I think there is a better way to write it and I didn't figure it out.
Plus I didn't manage to get the last expression which is Tt.
Anybody to help?

Comment: I would suggest that you use naming of your variables that is more closely related to the equation that you are calculating. However, CodeReview (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be more suited for your question here.

Comment: Are you sure the equation is correct? What is *t* doing in the second fraction, where it can't be the summation variable? Also note that the denominator of the first fraction can be simplified by letting the first sum run from *t* = 0 to T-1, so that the expressions under the sums are both the same...

Comment: I'll try it @E.Klahn, thanks for advising.

Comment: Please could you clarify? @Arne

Comment: Let me try this in pseudo-LaTex notation: sum_{t=1}^T (1 - d)^{t-1} = sum_{t=0}^{T-1} (1 - d)^t = 1 + sum_{t=1}^{T-1} (1 - d)^t, so the whole denominator of the first fraction in your formula equals 3 + sum_{t=1}^{T-1} (1 - d)^t. Anyway, here t is always given explicit values by the sum notation, so it is strange that t also appears in the other fraction, where there is no sum.